# HTML table layout 3x2

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of a situation that I need some help to figure it out.
I have a table that first row has three columns and the second row has two columns. I tried to play with `colspan` and `style` properties for the columns of the second row but I couldn't manage to make the second row to take 100% of the width of the table so I can center the items.

So now it takes 66% since the first rows has three columns.

[THIS IS MY CODE](https://jsfiddle.net/f64kga1x/)

P.S.

I already manged to make it using two tables but the result on mobile phone looks strange since the second table renders with different ration than the first one since it has only two columns.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is this going to be sent as an email? Otherwise: Please use CSS!

Comment: Create another table or simply dont use tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this :

```css
tr,td {
border:1px solid #000;
padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<table >
<tr>
<td colspan='2'>content</td>
<td colspan='2'>content</td>
<td colspan='2'>content</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='3'>content</td>
<td colspan='3'>content</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `colspan="2"` for the cells in the first row and `colspan="3"` for those in the second row. This adds up to 6 cells in each row which allows the distribution/division you want.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" align="center">
    <tbody>
       
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
              <h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Judith Steenvoorden<br /></span></h4>
              <h6 class="TextColor" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">voorzitter van College van Bestuur<br />
            van stichting ZAAM<br />
            </span><br />
            <div><br />
            </div>
            </h6>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Martine Bakker<br />
            </span></h4>
            <h6 class="TextColor" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">projectsecretaris van de Woltjer Stichting<br />
            </span><br />
            <div><br />
            </div>
            </h6>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Paul Rosenm&ouml;ller<br />
            </span></h4>
            <h6 class="TextColor" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">voorzitter van de VO-raad<br />
            </span><br />
            <div><br />
            </div>
            </h6>
            </td>
        </tr>
         
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Ruud van Baarsen<br />
            </span></h4>
            <h6 class="TextColor" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">leraar ABC Noorderlicht en verkozen<br />
            tot &lsquo;Meest inspirerende leerkracht&rsquo;<br />
            </span></h6>
            <br />
            <div><br />
            </div>
            </td>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
            <h4 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 18px;">Senna van Alphen<br />
            </span></h4>
            <h6 class="TextColor" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">van het Zuiderlicht College<br />
            <div><br />
            </div>
            </span><br />
            <div><br />
            </div>
            </h6>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but since @Temani Afif was first I have to accept his answer.

Comment: @Temani's answer is entirely incorrect and is not how to achieve colspans.

Comment: @Stuart what's incorrect about it? (and IF, you might write that as a comment to Temani's answer...)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will find it working. This is div structure without tables. You can look also https://codepen.io/ipg1421/pen/GMjxWd

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
    <div class="cell33">
        <h4>Judith Steenvoorden</h4>
        voorzitter van College van Bestuur<br />
        van stichting ZAAM<br />
    </div>
    <div class="cell33">
        <h4>Martine Bakker</h4>
        projectsecretaris van de Woltjer Stichting
    </div>
    <div class="cell33">
        <h4>Paul Rosenm&ouml;ller</h4>
        voorzitter van de VO-raad
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table; width: 100%;">
    <div class="cell50">
        <h4>Ruud van Baarsen</h4>
        leraar ABC Noorderlicht en verkozen<br />
        tot &lsquo;Meest inspirerende leerkracht&rsquo;<br />
    </div>
    <div class="cell50">
        <h4>Senna van Alphen</h4>
        van het Zuiderlicht College
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cell33 {
    width: 33%; 
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
.cell50 {
    width: 50%; 
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
```